# How do I utilize QComboBox's setSelectionMode to enable multiple seperate selections

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to build a combo box that allows multiple, discrete, selections. The [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) says I can either use `QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection` for toggling of each option or `QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection` for using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on each option.

However, no matter what I use, it seems to do two things wrong:

- Only one option ultimately remains selected
- The selection is contiguous *and* is done based on mouse over, not pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> like `QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection` seems to imply.

This is my example code (taken from [ZenCode's examples](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/widgets2/) for something simple)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem("Ubuntu")
        combo.addItem("Mandriva")
        combo.addItem("Fedora")
        combo.addItem("Red Hat")
        combo.addItem("Gentoo")
        combo.view().setSelectionMode(2)
        combo.move(50, 50)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output:

[image: Output]

For this output, I am not pressing any keys on the keyboard. Notice that it is attempting to select (or unselect) each item as I mouse over it. This causes flickering and if timed poorly, unselects an item.

How can I use the `setSelectionMode` and a `QCombobox` to prevent the flickering and automatic mouse over selection of items?

Comment: How do you want to combobox to display the multiple selection when the options are not displayed? It seems to me you would be better off using `QListWidget` or `QListView`.

Comment: I'm not that picky how it displays. It can show only one if it has to, but if I try to get the text from the selections, it only shows one.

Comment: The documentation only says this is possible from the abstract item view. While the combobox may use this, it doesn't mean it supports the behaviour you want. I don't think you're going to make it work (there are a few c++ questions around that end up implementing an entirely new widget). I would strongly recommend using `QListWidget` which is designed for this exact purpose.